# check if no parameters passed in groovy closure before calling it

Tags: groovy, closures

i use `maximumNumberOfParameters` to check  number of parameters used in closure ;

```
   def callerCls(Closure c){
     prinltn 'Nb :'+c.maximumNumberOfParameters;
      c();
  }
```

the pb that the follwing snippet has the same result .

```
  callerCls{


  }
 // and 
 callerCls{param1->

  }
```

Both of them return:

```
Nb :1
```

**Although** the follwing code,  returns `Nb :2`.

```
 callerCls{p1,p2->

      }
```

How to distinguish  closure where no parameter used (as the first snippet) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer had been found in [groovy official site](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures)

> **Parameter notes** A Closure without -> , i.e. {} , is a Closure with one
>   argument that is implicitly named as 'it'. (see below for details) In
>   some cases, you need to construct a Closure with zero arguments, e.g.
>   using GString for templating, defining EMC Property etc. You have to
>   explicity define your Closure as { -> } instead of just { }
>
> You can also use varargs as parameters, refer to the Formal Guide for
>   details. A JavaScript-style dynamic args could be simulated, refer to
>   the Informal Guide.